# How to update laravel eloquent where clause?

Tags: laravel

I have problem that query which is in $contracts_with_biba_accounting now is searching for accounting_id = 1 AND accounting_id = 2, but instead I want to search for accounting_id = 2.

```
$contracts_with_independent_accounting = $query->whereHas('institution', function($query) {
    $query->where('accounting_id', 1);
})->withTrashed()->get();

$contracts_with_biba_accounting = $query->whereHas('institution', function($query) {
    $query->where('accounting_id', 2);
})->get();
```

So, how can I fix this?

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Why do you base it off the same query parameter instead of a new one? i assume there is some logic you wanna keep, if so can you include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "clone" to obtain that.

```
contracts_with_independent_accounting = (clone $query)->whereHas('institution', function($query) {
    $query->where('accounting_id', 1);
})->withTrashed()->get();

$contracts_with_biba_accounting = (clone $query)->whereHas('institution', function($query) {
    $query->where('accounting_id', 2);
})->get();
```